# How to delete a file in linux that does not have any/garbage file permissions?

Tags: linux, file-management

How do I delete a file that does not have any file permissions ? I am not able to delete file forcefully or as superuser.

Please refer the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: what kind of remote filesystem is this? NAS? SAMBA?

Comment: It's a Vmware hgfs.

Comment: Can you change permissions on that file/directory?

Comment: No, not able to do that either, even as root.

Comment: More info please, the last time I've seen such a thing it was a defect harddisk.

Comment: This file is on virtual hard drive - VMware hgfs. As seen in the screenshot the permission are unkown and hence i am not able to make any changes to the file, even as a root. I do not know how that file was generated with such permissions, its a compiled output binary.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seemed to have mounted a folder from the VMware **host**, you will first need to make sure that you have the correct file permissions set on the host. Also, you can set the user and group ID of the mounted file system in `/etc/fstab` by adding `defaults,ttl=5,uid=1000,gid=1000` to the mount line. For more details see for example [this thread](http://communities.vmware.com/message/2014613).

Comment: Why would this happening to this particular file, since I files in other folders on same FS, which read / write / execute successfully ?

Comment: I suspect it's because the file has certain "special" permissions on the host FS or is in use by another process *somewhere*.

Comment: `UUID=2082e860-95ae-4ef6-8198-45b911bcab37 /    ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1`
The permission appear to be set correctly.

Comment: Is that the host file system? Can you delete the file there? Have you done a `fsck`?

Comment: Yes, I am able to delete the file there (on the host file system), but i am keen on learning how to handle such a condition on native Linux machine.

Comment: If all the other files are ok, this seems like a bug or an unexpected condition in the hgfs driver. If this is the case, there's really nothing you can do except report this as a bug to VMware.